# Execute command from query

Tags: sql, oracle, shell, sqlplus, mailx

I intend to send an email through the result of a query. the problem is that it is being printed instead of running the command. can someone explain to me what i am doing wrong?

```
sqlTxt=$(sqlplus -s "$CONNECT" << EOF 
   WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE;

   SET FEEDBACK OFF
   SET HEADING OFF
   SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
   SET FEED OFF
   SET TERMOUT OFF
   SET VERIFY OFF
   SET ECHO OFF
   SET HEAD OFF
select 'echo -en '||cme.BODY ||' |  mailx -s '||cme.SUBJECT ||' -a "$HTMLFILE"'||decode(MAIL_FROM,null,'',' -r "<' ||MAIL_FROM|| '>"')||' -c "'||MAIL_CC||'" "'||MAIL_TO||'"' send  from CUST_SEND_EMAIL cme WHERE  cme.program_name='SEND_EMAIL' and  cme.status='NOK';
/
EOF
)

$sqlTxt
```

Some additional notes:

- `cme.BODY` contains `\n` . for this reason I use `echo -en`
- i am using `mailx` because i found the simplest to work
- it is not mandatory to use the command as I did. I can assign to variables the content of each column resulting from the query (which I tried to do without success).

Someone can help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: that is not the problem. if so, the result was not printed (`echo -en` is working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the final line

```
$sqlTxt
```

to

```
eval $sqlTxt
```

More info [about eval](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/23116/33295), and [a warning](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048)!

> it adds a space to the file extension

That will be 80 characters in; nothing to do with the attachment per se, just SQL*Plus' default line width wrapping the result. If you keep the plain `$sqlTxt` as well you'll see the command it's trying to generate, which may have several spaces, at 80-char intervals - though if your terminal is set to 80 chars wide then that might not be obvious still.

You can override the line width with a high number, longer that you expect the command to ever be, e.g.

```
SET LINES 5000
```

You might want to enclose the subject in quotes too, in case that contains spaces; I was testing successfully with this slight variant:

```
...
   SET HEAD OFF
   SET LINES 5000

   select 'echo -en '
      || cme.BODY
      || ' |  mailx '
      || ' -s "' || cme.SUBJECT || '"'
      || ' -a "$HTMLFILE"'
      || case when MAIL_FROM is not null then ' -r "<' || MAIL_FROM || '>"' end
      || ' -c "' || MAIL_CC || '"'
      || ' "' || MAIL_TO || '"'
   from CUST_SEND_EMAIL cme
   where cme.program_name = 'SEND_EMAIL'
   and cme.status = 'NOK';
EOF
)

# to debug
$sqlTxt

eval $sqlTxt
```

Aside from splitting the query into multiple lines for readability and adding a few quotes, I also removed the `/`. As the query already ended with a semicolon that was just re-executing the buffer - which holds that query - so the output was duplicated, causing some odd results (extra spurious and illegal 'to' addresses).

Comment: works without the attachment. if you place the attachment it returns an error indicating that the file does not exist (it adds a space to the file extension [HTMLFILE.htm l instead of HTMLFILE.html])

Comment: @RCLFA - pretty sure that's SQL\*Plus splitting the output of the query onto multiple lines. Updated with a modified script that's working OK for me.